# Search Functionality with JQuery Autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I'm working on a project that involves creating an interface for a dictionary database. I was able to create a simple search bar that could pull out the correct information. Afterwards, I was able to implement an Autocomplete feature for the textbox using jQuery. Now, I'm having problems with the search function. If I submit the form, it does redirect to the appropriate script, but it does not send the text box value to the script.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>JQuery autocomplete example with database accessing</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            input.submit {
            width:30px;
            height:30px;
            cursor:pointer;
            background-image:url('../search-button.jpg');
        </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#searchbox" ).autocomplete({
            source: "data.php",
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
        <div style="background-color:#d4e7b2;text-align:left">
            <form action="../test.php" method="get" style="margin-left:1cm;">
                <div class="ui-widget">
                    <input id="searchbox"/>
                    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="" style="position:absolute;margin:0px 0 0 0px;"/>
                </div>

            </form>
            <br>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Autocomplete is working splendidly, but pressing the search button results in the page redirecting to "/test.php?" with no defined GET variables.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the name to your `searchbox` input.
change

```
<input id="searchbox"/>
```

to

```
<input name="searchbox" id="searchbox" />
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks so much!